# how to maxscript rename multiply object?

Tags: maxscript, 3ds

How can I change name prefix on multiple objects/bones?

For example:

```
object_123
object_234
object_345
```

I just want to change the name of the prefix `object_` which will be changed to `subject_` and the result will be like this:

```
subject_123
subject_234
subject_345
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use substituteString to do the string replacement, for example to change the prefix on selected objects with matching names you could do it like this:

```
for obj in selection where matchPattern obj.name pattern:"object_*" do
    obj.name = substituteString obj.name "object_" "subject_"
```